# Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0 (mp4)

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I've been using the [sickbeard_mp4_converter](https://github.com/mdhiggins/sickbeard_mp4_automator) for a while to convert video files to mp4 by generating a script for ffmpeg. I'm not sure what I changed, but the ffmpeg script it generates no longer works and I'm having trouble debugging it. Can anyone tell from my log what the issue is? Yes, its supposed to be an mp4 to an mp4, which is typically fine.

I'm at the point where I'm using an mp4 that worked with the same autogenerated script yesterday but it no longer is. I remember updating ffmpeg but downgrading did not resolve the issue, though I may have not downgraded enough.

ffmpeg 4.1.4

MediaInfo output:

```
$ mediainfo --fullscan Downloads/Dallas\ Buyers\ Club\ \(2013\).mp4.original 
General
Count                                    : 334
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Count of audio streams                   : 1
Video_Format_List                        : AVC
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : AVC
Codecs Video                             : AVC
Audio_Format_List                        : AAC LC
Audio_Format_WithHint_List               : AAC LC
Audio codecs                             : AAC LC
Audio_Language_List                      : English
Complete name                            : Downloads/Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4.original
Folder name                              : Downloads
File name extension                      : Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4.original
File name                                : Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4
File extension                           : original
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format/Extensions usually used           : braw mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p m4r 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Internet media type                      : video/mp4
Codec ID                                 : isom
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/avc1)
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
CodecID_Compatible                       : isom/avc1
File size                                : 1987698473
File size                                : 1.85 GiB
File size                                : 2 GiB
File size                                : 1.9 GiB
File size                                : 1.85 GiB
File size                                : 1.851 GiB
Duration                                 : 7017023
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min 57 s 23 ms
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min
Duration                                 : 01:56:57.023
Duration                                 : 01:56:58;17
Duration                                 : 01:56:57.023 (01:56:58;17)
Overall bit rate mode                    : VBR
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 2266144
Overall bit rate                         : 2 266 kb/s
Frame rate                               : 23.976
Frame rate                               : 23.976 FPS
Frame count                              : 168239
Stream size                              : 3690657
Stream size                              : 3.52 MiB (0%)
Stream size                              : 4 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.5 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.52 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.520 MiB
Stream size                              : 3.52 MiB (0%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.00186
HeaderSize                               : 3690598
DataSize                                 : 1984007824
FooterSize                               : 51
IsStreamable                             : Yes
Title                                    : Dallas Buyers Club
Movie name                               : Dallas Buyers Club
Director                                 : Jean-Marc Valle
Actor                                    : Matthew McConaughey / Jennifer Garner / Jared Leto / Denis O'Hare / Steve Zahn
Screenplay by                            : Craig Borten / Melisa Wallack
Producer                                 : Robbie Brenner / Rachel Winter / Kerry Barden / Rich Delia / Paul Schnee
Genre                                    : Drama
ContentType                              : Unknown Type
Description                              : Sometimes it takes a hustler to change the world
Recorded date                            : 2013-11-17
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-01-24 08:11:15
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-01-24 08:11:15
File last modification date              : UTC 2019-08-16 16:44:14
File last modification date (local)      : 2019-08-16 11:44:14
Writing application                      : MDH:Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4
Writing application                      : MDH:Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4
Cover                                    : Yes
ContentRating                            : mpaa|R|400|
LongDescription                          : Loosely based on the true-life tale of Ron Woodroof, a drug-taking, women-loving, homophobic man who in 1986 was diagnosed with HIV/AIDS and given thirty days to live.
FileExtension_Invalid                    : braw mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p m4r 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v

Video
Count                                    : 378
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 0
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format/Url                               : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Commercial name                          : AVC
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Internet media type                      : video/H264
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 7016967
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min 56 s 967 ms
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min
Duration                                 : 01:56:56.967
Duration                                 : 01:56:58;17
Duration                                 : 01:56:56.967 (01:56:58;17)
Bit rate                                 : 2169000
Bit rate                                 : 2 169 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 12300880
Maximum bit rate                         : 12.3 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1920
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 800
Height                                   : 800 pixels
Sampled_Width                            : 1920
Sampled_Height                           : 800
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.400
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.40:1
Rotation                                 : 0.000
Frame rate mode                          : CFR
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
FrameRate_Num                            : 24000
FrameRate_Den                            : 1001
Original frame rate                      : 23.976
Original frame rate                      : 23.976 (23976/1000) FPS
FrameRate_Original_Num                   : 23976
FrameRate_Original_Den                   : 1000
Frame count                              : 168239
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.059
Stream size                              : 1901715488
Stream size                              : 1.77 GiB (96%)
Stream size                              : 2 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.8 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.77 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.771 GiB
Stream size                              : 1.77 GiB (96%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.95674
Writing library                          : x264 - core 135 r2 f0c1c53
Writing library                          : x264 core 135 r2 f0c1c53
Encoded_Library_Name                     : x264
Encoded_Library_Version                  : core 135 r2 f0c1c53
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:-1:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x133 / me=umh / subme=9 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=24 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=36 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=2169 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / vbv_maxrate=31250 / vbv_bufsize=31250 / nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-01-24 08:11:15
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-01-24 08:11:38
colour_description_present               : Yes
colour_description_present_Source        : Stream
Color range                              : Limited
colour_range_Source                      : Stream
Color primaries                          : BT.709
colour_primaries_Source                  : Stream
transfer_characteristics_Source          : Stream
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
matrix_coefficients_Source               : Stream
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
Count                                    : 280
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 1
ID                                       : 2
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Commercial name                          : AAC
Format settings, SBR                     : No (Explicit)
Format settings, SBR                     : No (Explicit)
Format_AdditionalFeatures                : LC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 7017023
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min 57 s 23 ms
Duration                                 : 1 h 56 min
Duration                                 : 01:56:57.023
Duration                                 : 01:56:38:17
Duration                                 : 01:56:57.023 (01:56:38:17)
Bit rate mode                            : VBR
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 93816
Bit rate                                 : 93.8 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 107376
Maximum bit rate                         : 107 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Channel positions                        : 2/0/0
Channel layout                           : L R
Samples per frame                        : 1024
Sampling rate                            : 48000
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Samples count                            : 336817104
Frame rate                               : 46.875
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Frame count                              : 328923
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 82292328
Stream size                              : 78.5 MiB (4%)
Stream size                              : 78 MiB
Stream size                              : 78 MiB
Stream size                              : 78.5 MiB
Stream size                              : 78.48 MiB
Stream size                              : 78.5 MiB (4%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.04140
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : eng
Language                                 : en
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-01-24 08:11:37
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-01-24 08:11:38
```

Log:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "/Users/Me/Downloads/Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4.original" -vcodec libx264 -map 0:0 -vb 2063k -c:a:0 copy -map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -disposition:a:0 default -f mp4 -threads 0 -y "/Users/Me/Downloads/Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4"
ffmpeg version 4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc38e801400] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/Me/Downloads/Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4.original':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    title           : Dallas Buyers Club
    genre           : Drama
    date            : 2013-11-17
    encoder         : MDH:Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4
    media_type      : 9
    hd_video        : 2
    description     : Sometimes it takes a hustler to change the world
    synopsis        : Loosely based on the true-life tale of Ron Woodroof, a drug-taking, women-loving, homophobic man who in 1986 was diagnosed with HIV/AIDS and given thirty days to live.
    creation_time   : 2014-01-24T08:11:15.000000Z
  Duration: 01:56:57.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2266 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x750 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/unknown), 1920x800, 2168 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-24T08:11:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : video.264#trackID=1:fps=23.976 - Imported with GPAC 0.5.0-rev
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-24T08:11:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x7fc38e811000] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
[libx264 @ 0x7fc38e823e00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fc38e823e00] MB rate (135360000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 0x7fc38e823e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7fc38e823e00] profile High, level 6.2
[libx264 @ 0x7fc38e823e00] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=2063 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x7fc38e811000] Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
[libx264 @ 0x7fc38e823e00] final ratefactor: 89.20
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the mapping of your streams.
You have 3 input streams
0:0 mjpeg (probably a cover art)
0:1 mp4
0:2 aac audio

At the moment ffmpeg tries to convert 0:0 (mjpeg) to mp4

Use the following parameters to select your streams:
-map 0:1 -map 0:2

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! For some reason `-map 0:0 -map 0:1` was getting added to the script. Manually running ffmpeg with `-map 0:1 -map 0:2` successfully converted the video. Looks like the root of the problem was in the output of the converter `Video codec detected: mjpeg.`, which as you point out, is not correct and is likely the source of the bad mapping

Comment: If anyone else hits this from sickbeard_mp4_converter, manually running the ffmpeg command with the corrected mapping successfully reset stream identification so that the converter's autogeneration will work again: `ffmpeg -i "/Users/Me/Downloads/Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4.original" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2063k -c:a:0 copy -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -disposition:a:0 default -f mp4 -threads 0 -y "/Users/Me/Downloads/Dallas Buyers Club (2013).mp4"`

Comment: *Looks like the root of the problem was in the output of the converter* --> no. The first stream is indeed MJPEG. However, it's cover art and so has a disposition of attached picture. That disposition is carried over to the output. For attached pictures, the list of acceptable codecs doesn't include H.264. Without the disposition, the command would have succeeded.

Comment: I found I had to add `-map 0:0` to get an audio stream to convert without getting the above error.  Don't fully understand why.  In original, stream 0 was audio; stream 1 was `mjpeg` cover art.

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is a video encoded in motion jpeg (mjpeg). ffmpeg does not find H264 codec

`Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0`

First, try to get latest version of ffmpeg and they retry to encode your file.

If it doesn't work, try to change extension from .mp4 to .mpg and relaunch ffmpeg transcoding

Comment: The error is printed by the muxer, not the demuxer so it's unrelated to the source codec.